# creating an instance with all the fields of the parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

I have a Pojo named `A` and another Pojo named `B` which extends `A`:

```
public class A
{
    private String name;
    //constructor, setter and getter comes here.
}

public class B extends A
{
    private long id;
    //constructor, setter and getter comes here.
}
```

i have an instance of class `A` with a name.

```
A a = new A();
a.setName("udy");
```

I would like to get an instance of class `B` with all the values of `a` but without knowing what are the fields and values in `a`

Copy constructor wouldn't do the trick since when adding a field to `A`, i must update the copy constructor of `B`

[Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/usage.html) can do the trick, but i would like to avoid creating a copy.

i did some search but didn't find what i was looking for.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a copy ?

Comment: Take a look at BeanUtils from Apache.

Comment: The need to change the type of an object at runtime often signals a design weakness. Maybe you should rethink your concepts.

Comment: I fail to see why you might need this. If you told us, maybe we could suggest a better approach to solve your problem.

Comment: i would like to add some attributes in the extended object. but i want that my code will not know which fields i have in my parent object. another option would be to use composition instead of inheritance..

Comment: @bot i guess that `BeanUtils.copyProperties` is like using `dozer`, probobly my best solution here...